# How do I roleplay this Tribal / Segregated Community Character?

Tags: dnd-5e, roleplaying, background, aarakocra

I'm currently playing an Aarakocra Barbarian (Ancestral Spirit Guardian) that is the prophesied leader who will unite the scattered people. Standard Chosen One stuff. The Aarakocra tribes are not uncivilized, just spread out in the mountains, isolated, and unorganized.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to roleplay a character coming from this background. How do I make the character act? What personality traits might I have? What might be notable outlooks on life and such? What would be common methods of problem solving?

Anything to help play a character with this background would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to the stack Jackson, take the [tour] when you have a moment. Unfortunately, I don't think this question is a great fit for the stack, at least not in its current form. There's really no right or wrong answer here, so I'm voting to close as "opinion based". I think the question would be a better fit for a more traditional discussion forum, we here for our curated list: [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449). Or, with 20 rep, you can join us in [chat].

Comment: There are plenty of well received role-playing questions like [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71498/56975). I would recommend following their example and narrowing the focus of this question to a single question and I think this question can be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You Decide

In the end, really only you can decide who your character is. After all, there are infinite ways to play a "Chosen One".

You said, "standard Chosen One stuff". What does that mean to you? How do you picture a standard chosen one?

As Shakespeare said, "some are born to greatness, some aspire to it, some have it thrust upon them."  Were you born to a family of chosen ones? Do you want to be the chosen one? Are you forced by circumstances?

All the questions you asked are questions you should ask yourself.  Keep asking yourself questions and your character will begin to emerge. Are you brave? Reluctant? Do you even know you're the chosen one? What was your family like? Are they alive/dead? Are you a war leader, a spiritual leader, something else? Do people accept you as the chosen one? When you visit a village do they all cheer you, or not even recognize you, or even laugh at you?

You don't even have to decide these things now. Perhaps your character is just an acolyte or a petty criminal or a soldier, and *you the player* know they are destined to be the chosen one, but *they the character* don't. Perhaps whatever the defines them as the chosen one hasn't happened. Or maybe in the back of their mind they just *know* they are meant for bigger things, but they haven't figured out how to get traction yet.

### The "Backgrounds" feature may be useful to you

It sounds like you need a framework to help you decide what your character is like.  Consider taking a look at Chapter 4 of the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#PersonalityandBackground) or the Players Handbook.

Some example backgrounds are suggested.  You might consider picking one.  For instance, the Folk Hero might be suitable for a "chosen one", although perhaps something else may be more fitting.

If you don't like the backgrounds available to you, you can [customize a background](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#CustomizingaBackground).

The [Folk Hero](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#FolkHero) background suggests a "defining event". Looking at this may be helpful. If you don't like any of the defining events listed you can make up your own.  Consider these two defining events:

- I broke into a tyrant’s castle and stole weapons to arm the people.
- A celestial, fey, or similar creature gave me a blessing or revealed my secret origin.

Either one of these might fit a "chosen one", but would probably be very different characters.

Similarly, the Personality Trait and Ideal tables might help you further define your character.

### Talk to the DM and the other players

Generally you want to work with the DM at least a little to define your character. If the DM *told* you your character is "the chosen one", you might discuss in greater detail what they have in mind.  Or if you have come up with the idea of the chosen one, you might want to work out with the DM what that means.

The other players may or may not go along with your chosen one. After all, anyone can say, "I'm the chosen one!" But someone else can say, "Yeah, and so's my donkey. Get your own dang beer."

Whatever you work out, it's **your** story, and it's part of the bigger story told by the DM and the other players.